# ASP.Net MVC Model Binder - Ignore Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.Net MVC5 site using Entity Framework 6.

I am using ASP.Net Identity role-based security that performs granular security checks within the page to determine if certain input fields should be visible to the user.  i.e.

```
@if (User.IsInRole(MyProj.Security.Roles.ViewSocial)) {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.SSN)
}
```

If the user does not have the permission, the input field is not created and thus the model binder will blank out the value of this property.

How can I work this so that it ignores these properties in the case where they are not being displayed for edit?

`@Html.HiddenFor()` will not work because I can't have the tags included in the client-side HTML where the values can be seen in the source.

Will I need a custom model binder in this scenario?

Comment: Do you mean that you have validation attributes that are causing you model to be invalid when you post back?

Comment: I think OP means that a malicious user could post back form values that they shouldn't have access to. Trying to make it so that model binding only occurs for fields with which they are authorised.

Comment: When these fields are not created in the page, on post-back (for edits) the associated value in the database is set to NULL when it should retain its existing value.  This is the case when the initial record is created by someone with the permission, and subsequently edited by someone without it.

Comment: Then you should get the original model from the database, and update its  relevant properties from the view model

Comment: Ok, I can re-pull the original model in the POST on edit and put original values back if they don't have permissions (the ones the model binder wiped out).  I was just wondering if there was a better approach, it doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: I would argue its the ideal approach. A view model is always the best approach to render the view, and on post back, the data model is retrieved, updated based on the view model, and saved. The custom `ModelBinder` in the Jenish's answer may help encapsulate some of the authorization logic, but it still leaves the value of `SSN` null if `User.IsInRole` is `false` so your still facing the same problem - the saved value will be `null`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke return new instance is just for example. he would first get the instance he want to update by id from the db and then update the property in binder so in this way it wont be null.

Comment: Exactly, but OP was stating _it doesn't seem ideal_ (and all that's needed in the POST method is `@if (User.IsInRole(MyProj.Security.Roles.ViewSocial)) { model.SSN = viewModel.SSN };` (in which case the custom `ModelBinder` is not required)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I am recommending that approach because it would be reusable. any time he would access that model in controller, logic will not be required to be written again.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya, I not arguing against it (as I noted above in my 3rd comment). Just pointing out that it does not solve the problem of `NULL` being saved in the database.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it will solve that problem if he would fetch data from database in BindModel method and then assign relavant properties from request.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya, Yes I know. That's the whole point of all my comments (In response to OP's second comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should do something because even HTML input can be injected through developer tools in modern browser and it will get posted to the controller and you would believe he is authorized but he is actually not.

Yes definitely you need to prevent malicious user to do so. Two option is there.

1. you can do right logic of validating user by checking if he is authorized to do so or not.
2. As you suggested in the code apply custom model binder for that and only set that property if he is authorized to do so.

   ```
   public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
       if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(HomePageModels))
       {
           HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

           string title = request.Form.Get("Title");
           string day = request.Form.Get("Day");
           string month = request.Form.Get("Month");
           string year = request.Form.Get("Year");
           if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
           {
           string SSN = request.Form.Get("SSN");
           }
           return new HomePageModels
           {
               Title = title,
               Date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year,
               SSN = SSN
           };
           //// real time HomePageModels instance should be loaded from database here to avoid saving null if person is not authorized to do so 
       }
       else
       {
           return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Good point about injection of the secured fields.  I went with this approach but cleaned it up a bit.  I called to the default model binder and then simply overwrote values with the values from the original model where the user did not have the proper security.  It works as expected.

Comment: I know this is old but a better solution would be to override GetModelProperties() and then exclude any properties that shouldn't be bound from the return value - thus inheriting from the defaultbinder does most of the work. You could create an attrib to put on the property which security role applies to the field thus the custom binder would not have to be so tightly coupled and could be generalised more.